# How FB web services interact with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, facebook-login

I know that web services are used to call a method of other application which returns the results to the form application in asp.net. But if I am using the "login with FB" method then how does the FB web service interact  with the interface of my web application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using FBJS, and last time I checked this was the preferred way of doing it, there is no direct interaction. After someone completes the FB login process, you will have access to a FB cookie. Then, on the server with C#, you will need to manually look for that cookie and do something with it, such as create your own authentication token using [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I read somewhere that web services returns only the result of the called method and next time when we request then the web service take it as a new request. If this is the case then there is no chance we can manage the state between the different requests of the same user .

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say "web services". That is a pretty broad term that can refer to many different things. Of course you can manage state: that is what sessions and cookies are for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implement it, you can use javascript in which case it is all done client side or you could use something like:

> > using ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI;

Which would allow you to use server controls and their click event to log into facebook. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I meant to say that if web services are stateless then how do they maintain the state of a logged in user ?

Comment: Like jeff said, you have to use state management ie: session variables, etc... With a facebook login, I believe you are given a token, which you only need to refresh periodically.

Comment: I am asking about the web services implementation on FB server.